# Error:Execution failed for task ':Renters:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'

Tags: android, error-handling

while eclipse project imported into android Studio i am getting the Below error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':Renters:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.class

Comment: try with Build/Clean Project